# В старом проекте неактивны некоторые элементы toolbox

Tags: c#

В старом проекте не могу добавить некоторые элементы, в частности chart, видно его только если использовать опцию "показать все", при создании нового проекта win forms такой элемент активен сразу, сброс панели не помог

Comment: [Chart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.8#moniker-applies-to) появился в .NET FW 4.0. Насколько старый тот проект, под какую версию фреймворка?

Comment: Создан был когда устанавливал 19 студию, как посмотреть не знаю, но помню что когда то при установке выбирал 4.7.1 или что то похожее...

Comment: Откройте свойства решения справа в Solution Explorer, там где дерево файлов и посмотрите в свойствах Target Framework.

Comment: уфф, кажется я понял, там .NET Core 3.1

Comment: В .NET Core 3.1 есть новый дизайнер для форм.